# Задать IP адрес на этапе билда машины

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, виртуализация, kvm

Категорически приветствую! Допустим, существует некий абстрактный сервер с `centos 7` и `libvirt + libguestfs (virt-(builder,install,sysprep,customize и иже с ними))` на борту. Пытаюсь сбилдить новую виртуальную машину

```
# virt-builder centos-7.6 \
--format qcow2 \
--size 10G \
--hostname test-1.local \
--timezone Asia/Kolkata \
-o /images/test-1.qcow2

# virt-install --import --name test-1 \
--memory 1024 --vcpus 1 --cpu host \
--disk /images/test-1.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio \
--network bridge=br121 \
--os-type=linux \
--os-variant=centos7.0 \
--graphics spice \
--noautoconsole
```

Всё замечательно, скачивается предустановленный образ, билдится, расширяется диск и создаётся новая машина. Всё вроде бы хорошо но есть несколько вопросов которые никак не могу решить с помощью libguestfs:

1. Как задать статичный IP (**БЕЗ dhcp**, просто адрес из пула 192.168.0.0/24) адрес с помощью (любой из) утилит libguestfs ?
2. Возможно ли, и если да то как менять разметку диска?

**UPD**
Частично отвечая а первый вопрос, нашёл такой способ `--upload /root/ifcfg-eth0:/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (Где `/root/ifcfg-eth0` это заранее сконфигурированный как нужно интерфейс) , в принципе вариант рабочий, но может как-то "лучше" можно это сделать? Может, какие-то встроенные методы из коробки есть?

Answer (score 1):

Редактируешь сеть

```
sudo virsh net-edit default

<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>2cf9a1fe-2da2-4e7d-92a7-5785163ab1c4</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:d9:f7:22'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Там настроить можно подсеть, а статический адрес задается записями

```
  <host mac="52:54:00:6f:78:f3" ip="192.168.122.222"/>
```

Добавить привязку можно командой

```
virsh net-update default add-last ip-dhcp-host \
      '<host mac="52:54:00:6f:78:f3" ip="192.168.122.222"/>' \
      --live --config --parent-index 0
```

Укажите мак адрес в полученный в виртуалке.

[Вот тут подробнее](https://jamielinux.com/docs/libvirt-networking-handbook/appendix/dhcp-host-entries.html)

Либвирт раздает адреса через  dnsmasq. Править эти конфиги нет смысла - перезапишутся.

```
/usr/bin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
```

Comment: Это всё замечательно и я благодарен за совет, но есть одна небольшая проблема - у меня **нет** dhcp и он мне не нужен от слова _совсем_ :) Вот этот бридж `--network bridge=br121` существует на хосте гипервизоре и содержит сеть `192.168.0.0/24` , так вот мне нужно присваивать статичный адрес из этой сети на этапе билда машины :) Добавлю это в топик чтоб снова не возникло оказий :)

Comment: заливать файл у вас уже получется и это нормальный способ если нет дхчп)